# Delete the default instance of SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7

I'm trying to uninstall SQL Server 2008. I went through add remove programs and deleted all the SQL Server programs which didn't remove the services and the instances... I manually deleted the services using command prompt and I even tried deleted the SQL Server directories from program files and program files (x86).

I want to install SQL Server 2008 R2 so I can import data from a back up file from a db on another server. But when I try to install R2 it says the default instance is already being used. How do I get rid of the default instance from the original SQL Server?

Comment: This was for 2008 R2 eval edition, but perhaps some of the same techniques would be useful for 2008: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/10/25/fun-with-software-uninstalling-sql-server-2008-r2-evaluation-edition.aspx

Comment: You might also try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955404